# It's possible to set fullscreen through application on a VM?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, x11

I convert some code from *Windows API* to a hardware-virtualised (VirtualBox) *Lubuntu linux (14.04 ubuntu)* and wanted to add cross-platform *fullscreen* functionality. I'm using the `XF86` Xlib extension for this. My code for changing the display mode is the following (only the relevant part)

```
  int width = 800;
  int height = 600;

  ..some code to make sure the above dimensions are supported by current screen

  int modesnum;
  XF86VidModeModeInfo** modes;
  if (XF86VidModeGetAllModeLines(display,0,&modesnum,&modes)) {
     for(int x=0;x<modesnum;x++) {
        if (modes[x]->hdisplay==width && modes[x]->vdisplay==height) {
           XF86VidModeSwitchToMode(display,0,modes[x]);
           XF86VidModeSetViewPort(display,0,0,0);
           break;
        }
     }
  }
```

When i compile + run the above on my VM the result isn't the expected. My VM resolution is *1366x768* (laptop) and running it on a fullscreen VM it doesn't really change to fullscreen rather makes a smaller viewport of *800x600* in the center of my previous desktop resolution with a black background. I know of course i'm running the OS in a virtual machine and some quirks are expected, i just wanted to verify if it's just *impossible* to kick out a clean fullscreen and not some fake, scaled stuff made by VM.

I run the same application to another virtualised machine (WinXP) and i got the same scaled fullscreen, so i suppose not possible? I just want to verify if my linux code correctly set the fullscreen and it's just VM that mangles the fullscreen by giving me a scaled version.

Comment: No, your app running inside a VM can't set fullscreen of the *physical* host.  And yes, your app can go "full screen" ... as determined by what Virtualbox tells it is "full screen".  Your virtualized app can utilize the full virtual screen.  That's it :)

Comment: Thank you :) i had α suspicion for that, i just wanted to verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `NO`.The app running inside the virtual manager can be set on the full screnn on the other 
host.It can be made full screen when the Virtualbox accepts it as full screen as @Foggyday mentioned ..Thanx..:)